# How to show the given set is convex or not?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

The set is defined as
$$ V=\{(1,\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))|0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2\}.$$
Using the definition of convex set, this is how I tried.
Let $$ v_1,v_2 \in V,$$ then $$v_1 =(1,\cos(\theta_1),\sin(\theta_1))$$ and $$v_2=(1,\cos(\theta_2),\sin(\theta_2)) $$ where $ 0 \leq \theta_1,\theta_2 \leq \pi/2.$ Now for $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$, $$ \lambda v_1+(1-\lambda)v_2 =(1,\lambda \cos(\theta_1)+(1-\lambda)\cos(\theta_2),\lambda \sin(\theta_1)+(1-\lambda)\sin(\theta_2)).$$
So we need to show either that there exists some $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ such that $$ \cos(\theta)= \lambda \cos(\theta_1)+(1-\lambda)\cos(\theta_2)$$ and $$\sin(\theta)=\lambda \sin(\theta_1)+(1-\lambda)\sin(\theta_2),$$ or no such $\theta$ exists. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Isn't this a quarter circle in $R^3?$ This is not convex because you can draw straight lines between points in the set and points on the straight lines are not in the set.

Comment: $@$ Adam Rubinson Yes, it is. But in that case any curve won't be non-convex right? But in $R^2$, we say a curve is convex if the line joining two points on the curve lies above the curve.

Comment: "in $\mathbb R^2$, we say a curve is convex if the line joining two points on the curve lies above the curve" No we do not. For example, the curve $C = \{(x,y) \mid y = x^2 \}$ is not a convex subset of $\mathbb R^2$. You're mixing up the idea of a convex function and a convex set.

Comment: $@$ littleO Thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your concern in the comment section.

In fact convexity of curves and convexity of sets are related in this way:

In $\mathbb R^2$ the function $y=f(x)$ is convex if the set $S(f)=\{(x,y)\mid y\ge f(x)\}$ is convex, that is the region above the curve of $y=f(x)$ is convex.

The convexity of the set is given any two points, the segment joining these two points also belongs to the set (or algebraically $\lambda P_1+(1-\lambda)P_2\in S,\ \forall \lambda\in[0,1]$).

For a convex curve, this segment is above the curve, therefore in the region defined by $S$.

Now if a continuous curve can define $2$ regions in $\mathbb R^2$ (let stay in the simple case where there is no self-intersecting, this is just for illustration anf comprehension) in $\mathbb R^3$ you'll need a surface to achieve that.

But since the first coordinate $1$ is fixed, the resulting curve is just the quarter circle of dimension $1$ and we cannot apply the definition seen above.

Moreover you gave us directly a set and not a curve, so geetha290km counter-example solves the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

$(1,0,1) \in V$ (corresponding to $\theta=\frac {\pi} 2$), $(1,1,0) \in V$ (corresponding to $\theta=0$),  but $\frac 1 2 [(1,0,1)+(1,1,0)] \notin V$ because there is no $\theta$ with $\sin \theta =\cos \theta =\frac  12$.